# Planning assistant is greyed out. office 365 - outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-365

**Hello. All the Super users.**

**THE PROBLEM:**
Our assistant can not see someone's calendar in planning assistant they are greyed out, while she can see others' calendars just fine.

In the calendar overview, she can see everyone's calendar.

but when she calls in for meetings and has added everyone who is going to the meeting, someone becomes greyed out in the planning assistant.

I have deleted the cache and made sure it does not save any cache.
unsuccessfully.

I have no problem seeing people in the planning assistant, we have the same rights, so do not understand.
She can see everything via portal.office.com but not on the PC.

[example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIeaW.png)

**what we want to work:**
She needs to be able to see everyone's calendar in the planning assistant

looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0):

Could it work normally if the user works in online mode? I noticed that you seem to have emptied the autocomplete list, is it right? And did the issue have any difference if she type the full user's address manually in the attendee field? If it could work normally when you type address manually, the issue may be related to your address book, maybe you could try to download a new OAB to check.

If it still couldn't work, as I know, any add-ins may also cause this issue, in order to avoid the interference of them, it's suggested to restart your outlook in safe mode for testing.